# add array to object which is inside array of objects if second array of object has same value

Tags: javascript, arrays

So if I have two array with same key and value:

```
var firstArr = [{name:'Lorem', post_id:2},{name:'Ipsum', post_id:1}];
var secondArr = [{sec:'Deca', another_id:2},{sec:'Meca', another_id:1},{sec:'Raca', another_id:2}];
```

What i want to achieve is when:

```
firstArr.map(function(item,i) {
if(item.post_id === secondArr[i].another_id) {
   item.randKey = secondArr[i]
}

});
```

But the output of this is wrong 
result is

```
firstArr[0];
Object {name: "Lorem", post_id: 2, randKey: Array(1)}
```

What i want to achieve is that

```
 firstArr[0];
    Object {name: "Lorem", post_id: 2, randKey: Array(2) = {sec:'Deca', another_id:2},{sec:'Raca', another_id:2} }
```

So my question is it only appends one array, but it should append both if (post_id =2 === another_id = 2)

I am hoping i was clear enough.

Comment: what is the content of `randKey: Array(2)`?

Comment: you need  array push

Comment: @NinaScholz I have edited my question

Comment: *map* creates a new array from the values returned by the callback function. Your function always returns undefined and you don't use the returned array (which is full of undefined values), you modify the original array, so you should be using *forEach*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`Array#forEach`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi06Z_cwZnUAhUkSI8KHT0nB6kQFgg-MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FforEach&usg=AFQjCNFWWfwOQKjXdfPWyAU9FxufcTqwMg&sig2=7jKydEu1zkBiBWFi4lo8uQ) for iterate the `firstArray`  and [`Array#filter`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjb-_PmwZnUAhUfS48KHU28AbUQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffilter&usg=AFQjCNHgB7IyOa22NG7kCsGZ1ldwMUmkiA&sig2=HcLquwQJQrCnXS43IgCRmA) used for filter the `secondArr` with respected `postid` match

```js
var firstArr = [{name:'Lorem', post_id:2},{name:'Ipsum', post_id:1}];
var secondArr = [{sec:'Deca', another_id:2},{sec:'Meca', another_id:1},{sec:'Raca', another_id:2}];


 firstArr.forEach(function(item,i) {
  item.randKey = secondArr.filter(a=> a.another_id == item.post_id)
});

console.log(firstArr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: *item.randKey* should probably be conditional on there being elements to push into the array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temporary object for collecting all items of `secondArr` with the same `another_id`. Then iterate `firstArr` and assign the collected items.

```js
var firstArr = [{ name: 'Lorem', post_id: 2 }, { name: 'Ipsum', post_id: 1 }],
    secondArr = [{ sec: 'Deca', another_id: 2 }, { sec: 'Meca', another_id: 1 }, { sec: 'Raca', another_id: 2 }],
    temp = {};

secondArr.forEach(function (a) {            
    temp[a.another_id] = temp[a.another_id] || [];
    temp[a.another_id].push(a);            
});

firstArr.forEach(function (a) {
    a.randKey = temp[a.post_id];
});

console.log(firstArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```